# linear algebra $\det(I+A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order 2 such that $AA^T=I$. If $\det(A) < 0$, find $\det(I+A)$.

I managed to find $\det(A)$ which is $-1$, but I do not know how to proceed from here. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: By "order 2" you mean the matrix is $2 \times 2$ or that the rank is $2$?

Comment: its a 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\det(I+A)=
\det(A^TA + A)=
\det(A^T + I)\det(A)=\\
\det(I+A)\det(A)
$$

Comment: i havent learn about eigenvalues yet. Still new to linear algebra

Comment: See my updated answer. Feel free to ask about any steps here.

Comment: oh thanks bro, so det(I+a) has to be zero.. my only question why is det(A^t+I)=det(A+I)

Comment: For any two matrices $n\times n$ matrices $C$ and $B$ $(C+B)^T = C^T+B^T$. We also know that for any matrix $\mathrm{det}(A^T) = \text{det}(A)$. From this you can get that $\mathrm{det}(A^T+I) = \text{det}((A^T+I)^T) = \mathrm{det}(A+I^T) = \text{det}(A+I) $.

Comment: @Ken thanks for stepping in there.

Answer (score 0):

$AA^{t}=I$ gives that matrix $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal matrix. Therefore condition det$A<0$ gives, eigen values of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$ and hence that of $I+A$  are $0$ and $2$. So $$|I+A|=0.$$